# Make a temporary DB connection without losing the original default connection

Tags: php, mysql

I have a very large and unstructured script.

At some point in the script, a DB connection is made.

Some time after that point I need to make a new connection to another DB, run a query then disconnect.

After I've done this, I need all subsequent mysql_query() calls to use the original DB link.

I know I can capture the link identifier from the first mysql_connect(), and use that in all relevant mysql_query() calls, but I don't want to modify any more code than I have to. I'm looking to do something like this:

```
//... loads of code ...

mysql_connect("original connection");
mysql_query(...); // don't want to modify these lines

//... loads more code ...

$link = get_current_mysql_link_identifier(); // imaginary function
$new_link = mysql_connect("my new connection");
mysql_query(...); // uses new connection
mysql_close($new_link);
reinstate_old_link($link); // imaginary function

//... loads more code ...

mysql_query(...) // line remains unchanged. uses original DB link
```

Without those imaginary function, once the second connection is closed, mysql_query() does not default to the original connection; it continues to try and use the more recent, closed connection.

Comment: I think, **but** I could well be **wrong** that once the second connection is closed the `mysql_`* functions will operate on the next available connection, which in this case would be the first connection.

Comment: Not an elegant solution but why you don't reconnect to the first database after you're done with your secondary database queries?

Comment: @Treffynnon I've done some tests, and it appears that it doesn't fall-back to the original question after the mysql_close()

Comment: @Raisen That's an option, but I'm dealing with some really convoluted code and I'm not 100% sure where the connection came from!

Comment: Instead of reinstate_old_link() just call mysql_connect with the original connection parameters again. The documentation says that in this case an existing connection will be reused...

Comment: Hi strauberry, @Raisen already suggested this, 3 comments up

Answer (score 1):

[`mysql_connect()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) returns a reference to the connection, which you can then provide on other statements to indicate the connection to be used.  I believe you also have to specify the `new_link` argument to create a new connection.

Comment: Hi Jim. Quoting my original question: "I know I can capture the link identifier from the first mysql_connect(), and use that in all relevant mysql_query() calls, but I don't want to modify any more code than I have to". It looks like what I want to achieve is not possible.